# C# byte[] to C++ unsigned char* - Crash on Android, fine on Windows

Tags: c#, android, c++

First question here, been trying to fix this problem for the past week but I am stuck.

I am passing a byte array from C# to C++. The C++ dll only needs to **read** the data, there is no passing back from C++ to C#.

On the C++ side:

```
void bytefunc(unsigned char* tex, int length){

   for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

                           a[i]=b[i]; //definition and memory for a is already allocated 

       }


}
```

On the C# side:

```
[DllImport ("dll")];
private static extern void bytefunc(byte[] byteArr, int length);
........
bytefunc(barr,len) //all the variables are set properly before calling
```

This bit of code works perfectly fine on Windows machines, no matter how long I run it for. We recently moved our application to android, and the app crashes at random times, in fact sometimes it doesn't crash at all. After hours of debugging, I have pinpointed that this bit of code is the culprit, since the SIGSEGV is always here. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any alternate way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You should be defining a Marshal on the C# side to make sure you serialize the data properly. Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Have you checked the values of `byteArr` and `length` when it crashes?